# How can we build an expression tree from a given infix expression in C++ and evaluate it?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

what are the rules of parsing infix expression into tree and also of evaluating it?Do we have to first convert infix to postfix or prefix before converting it into a tree or we directly do this while in infix form?

Comment: First of all, you need converter from infix to postfix. Then you can evaluate the expression

Comment: Generally, the tree is produced directly from the infix form while parsing.  If you only need to evaluate the expression once, then you usually don't even need the the tree, because you can evaluate it while parsing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it necessary to convert infix notation to postfix when creating an expression tree from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610626/is-it-necessary-to-convert-infix-notation-to-postfix-when-creating-an-expression)