# function that solves operator precedence

Tags: algorithm, sorting, programming-languages

I have a problem that I can't wrap my head around.

My input is a flat list like this: (and I can tell what's the next operator, and what's the next element)

```
element, operator, element, operator, element, operator...
```

And I need to look at each and order them in precedence they have. They can be either `right` or `left` associative and either `after`, `same`, `before` or `undefined`.

Also there is `Expr` which is either `Value` or `Op(Expr, operator, Expr)`

The finished product should be a tree of `Exprs`:

```
       [ Expr ]
        / * \
       /     \
      /       \
 [ Expr ]  [ Expr ]
            / + \
           /     \
          /       \
      [ Expr ]  [ Expr ]
```

That read left to right, should be the correct ordering of operators, according to the rules.

I have functions, that can tell me if the relation of operators is `before`, `after`, `same`, `undefined`
and if either are associative: `right` or `left`

---

I need a function, that can be recursively called, and finally returns one `Expr`, that contains the whole tree.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610626/is-it-necessary-to-convert-infix-notation-to-postfix-when-creating-an-expression/42612892#42612892

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at Dijkstra's [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). The algorithm will parse a list of tokens (i.e. elements and operators) and output the Abstract Syntax Tree, which is what you have described above.

The algorithm runs in O(n) time and supports operator precedence and associativity.

Comment: Yes, this might be even a better option. Just keep it in Reverse polish notation, then parse it away. Didn't thought of this, but seems the best option, and can be easily made in functional programming.