# How to write a parser to construct the JavaScript AST MemberExpression for the expression a.b[c.d][e].f[g[h[i.j]]]?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, path

Following along the lines of [How to clearly represent a.b[c.d][e].f[g[h[i.j]]] as an object tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70078734/how-to-clearly-represent-a-bc-de-fghi-j-as-an-object-tree), how would you write an algorithm to generate that JS AST from the expression `a.b[c.d][e].f[g[h[i.j]]]`? I am trying to write a parser to generate some sort of object structure from this expression (ideally more intuitive than the JS AST `MemberExpression` one, hence that other question). I would like to see how the algorithm works to construct the JavaScript `MemberExpression` tree.

Currently I have this sort of algorithm to generate *some sort of* tree (but it seems to be incorrect currently):

```js
const patterns = [
  [/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*/, 'name'],
  [/^\[/, 'open'],
  [/^\]/, 'close'],
  [/^\./, 'stem']
]

console.log(parsePath('a.b[c.d][e].f[g[h[i.j]]]'))

function parsePath(str) {
  let node
  let nest = []
  let result = nest
  let stack = [nest]
  while (str.length) {
    nest = stack[stack.length - 1]
    p:
    for (let pattern of patterns) {
      let match = str.match(pattern[0])
      if (match) {
        if (pattern[1] === 'name') {
          node = {
            form: `term`,
            name: match[0],
            link: []
          }
          nest.push(node)
        } else if (pattern[1] === 'stem') {
          stack.push(node.link)
        } else if (pattern[1] === 'open') {
          node = {
            form: 'read',
            link: []
          }
          nest.push(node)
          stack.push(node.link)
        } else if (pattern[1] === 'close') {
          stack.pop()
        }

        str = str.substr(match[0].length)
        break p
      }
    }
  }
  return result[0]
}
```

The desired result is this (or a better, more intuitive data structure if you are so inclined to create one):

```
{
  "type": "MemberExpression",
  "object": {
    "type": "MemberExpression",
    "object": {
      "type": "MemberExpression",
      "object": {
        "type": "MemberExpression",
        "object": {
          "type": "MemberExpression",
          "object": {
            "type": "Identifier",
            "name": "a"
          },
          "property": {
            "type": "Identifier",
            "name": "b"
          },
          "computed": false
        },
        "property": {
          "type": "MemberExpression",
          "object": {
            "type": "Identifier",
            "name": "c"
          },
          "property": {
            "type": "Identifier",
            "name": "d"
          },
          "computed": false
        },
        "computed": true
      },
      "property": {
        "type": "Identifier",
        "name": "e"
      },
      "computed": true
    },
    "property": {
      "type": "Identifier",
      "name": "f"
    },
    "computed": false
  },
  "property": {
    "type": "MemberExpression",
    "object": {
      "type": "Identifier",
      "name": "g"
    },
    "property": {
      "type": "MemberExpression",
      "object": {
        "type": "Identifier",
        "name": "h"
      },
      "property": {
        "type": "MemberExpression",
        "object": {
          "type": "Identifier",
          "name": "i"
        },
        "property": {
          "type": "Identifier",
          "name": "j"
        },
        "computed": false
      },
      "computed": true
    },
    "computed": true
  },
  "computed": true
}
```

The reason I'm struggling (partially) is I don't like this `MemberExpression` tree structure, it's backward feeling and not very intuitive. So if you could construct a simpler more straightforward data structure that would be ideal (that was the other question), but if not then just an algorithm to construct this would get me going.

Personally, I would rather try to generate this structure, as I find it more intuitive:

```
{
  type: 'site',
  site: [
    {
      type: 'term',
      term: 'a'
    },
    {
      type: 'term',
      term: 'b'
    },
    {
      type: 'sink',
      sink: [
        {
          type: 'term',
          term: 'c'
        },
        {
          type: 'term',
          term: 'd'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'sink',
      sink: [
        {
          type: 'term',
          term: 'e'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'term',
      term: 'f'
    },
    {
      type: 'sink',
      sink: [
        {
          type: 'term',
          term: 'g'
        },
        {
          type: 'sink',
          sink: [
            {
              type: 'term',
              term: 'h'
            },
            {
              type: 'sink',
              sink: [
                {
                  type: 'term',
                  term: 'i'
                },
                {
                  type: 'term',
                  term: 'j'
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But either one works for me (or both).

If we go with the second one, my next problem will be how to convert that data structure into the `MemberExpression` tree/data structure :) But I'll try and do that myself first. So it's probably better to construct the MemberExpression in this question, then I can work off that.

Comment: Okay I've added it.

Comment: _"How to write a parser"_ is _quite_ broad. And what exactly does _"seems to be incorrect"_ mean?

Comment: This is not broad _at all_. It's a simple thing to parse (well, I am having some trouble on it), it's not like I'm asking to parse a programming language. I've already partially parsed it. Seems to be incorrect means, it doesn't give a data structure that accurately/usefully captures the input.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610626/is-it-necessary-to-convert-infix-notation-to-postfix-when-creating-an-expression/42612892#42612892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Separate the string into groups of object and properties of the first level, like

   ```
   [
       "a",
       "b",
       "[c.d]",
       "[e]",
       "f",
       "[g[h[i.j]]]"
   ]
   ```
2. Get the object

   1. Take the last item as property.
   2. Check if the property start with bracket then set `computed` to `true` and strip the property from the surrounding brackets.
   3. Return an object with

      - `type: "MemberExpression"` ,
      - `object` with the object (2.),
      - `property` with the result of calling the main function `getAST` (1.),
      - `computed`.

```js
function getAST(string) {

    function getObject(parts) {
        if (parts.length === 1) return { type: "Identifier", name: parts[0] };

        let property = parts.pop(),
            computed = false;

        if (property.startsWith('[')) {
            computed = true;
            property = property.slice(1, -1);
        }

        return {
            type: "MemberExpression",
            object: getObject(parts),
            property: getAST(property),
            computed
        };
    }

    let i = 0,
        dot,
        bracket,
        parts = [];

    while (i < string.length) {
        dot = string.indexOf('.', i);
        bracket = string.indexOf('[', i);

        if (dot !== -1 && (bracket === -1 || dot < bracket)) {
            const temp = string.slice(i, dot);
            if (temp) parts.push(temp);
            i = dot + 1;
            continue;
        }

        if (bracket !== -1 && (dot === -1 || bracket < dot)) {
            const temp = string.slice(i, bracket);
            if (temp) parts.push(temp);
            i = bracket;

            let open = 1,
                j = i;

            while (++j < string.length) {
                if (string[j] === '[') open++;
                if (string[j] === ']') open--;
                if (!open) break;
            }

            j++;
            parts.push(string.slice(i, j));

            i = j;
            continue;
        }
        parts.push(string.slice(i));
        break;
    }

    return getObject(parts);
}

console.log(getAST('a.b[c.d][e].f[g[h[i.j]]]'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```