# How to Handle Left Associativity for Logical Operators in a Recursive Descent Parser?

Tags: bash, algorithm, parsing, recursive-descent

I'm implementing a recursive descent parser for a mini-shell program based on bash, where typically, right recursion is applied. However, for logical operators `&&` and `||`, this approach doesn't seem convenient for execution.

For instance, when parsing a command sequence such as `cmd1 && cmd2 || cmd3`, the right recursive parser would generate a tree like this:

```
     &&
    /   \
cmd1    ||
        /  \
    cmd2   cmd3
```

However, for the execution to follow the bash logic correctly, it's more suitable to have left associativity for `&&` and `||` operators, resulting in a tree like this:

```
    ||
   /  \
&&   cmd3
/ \
cmd1 cmd2
```

Given this scenario, what would be the recommended approach to modify the parser to handle left associativity specifically for && and || operators while maintaining right associativity for others? Would it involve a change in the parsing algorithm or a post-processing step after parsing? Or there is a way to execute the tree with right associativity according to bash?

Comment: @trincot Usually, in shells `&&`and `||` have the same precedence

Comment: A recursivedecent parser follows grammar rules replacing a LHS with the corresponding RHS starting with the start symbol. These rules can be left- or right-recursive, which directly maps to left- or right associativity of your parse tree (`T: CMD | CMD "&&" T | CMD "||" T` vs. `T: CMD | T "&&" CMD | T "||" CMD`). This directly maps to the associativity of the operators. However, a recursive-decent parser might have trouble with leftrecursive rules because it easily gets stuck in an infinite regression. There are ways around (breadth-search), or you just use bison to create an LALR(1) parser

Comment: If this isn't for parsing C, then what does C have to do with the question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610626/is-it-necessary-to-convert-infix-notation-to-postfix-when-creating-an-expression/42612892#42612892

Comment: @Lundin Maybe they're implementing the parser in C? Although in that case they should post their current code for it.

Comment: If you're asking how to modify your code, you need to post the current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In the POSIX shell syntax, the && and || operators have the same precedence and associate left to right.

Using Bash-specific curly brace syntax we can understand it as:

```
A op1 B op2 C      <-->    { A op1 B } op2 C
```

for `op1` and `op2` being any combination of the `||` and `&&` operators.

(We can't use parentheses to show this because they introduce a semantic action of execution in a "subshell" process.)

The shell executes commands separated by these operators from left to right. When the separator is `&&`, the command so far must be successful in order to continue. When the separator is `||`, the command so far must have failed.

Parsing this is the same like handling `A + B - C ...`. Recursive descent parsing identifies as LL(k) (usually k = 1), whereas left association more naturally pairs with LR parsing. A grammar structure like:

```
E := E && E
  |  E || E
```

is "left factored" for LL(1) parsing.  You don't have to do this formally. There is a code structure which handles the case. The basic structure is:

1. Parse an expression; call it `E`.
2. While the next token is `&&` or `||`:

   - consume token, call it `operator`.
   - parse expression which follows, call it `Enext`.
   - build tree node by combining existing expression with new one: `E := make_node(E, operator, Enext)`.
   - loop from (2)
3. Return E